# How to apply NXOR on 2 bits in c

Tags: c

I have two bits in C language and I want o perform bitwise NXOR operator on them. I.e:

```
a=0,b=0 or a=1,b=1 -> NXOR(a,b)=1
a=1,b=0 or b=1,a=0 -> NXOR(a,b)=0
```

Any easy way to perform this? I know that the XOR operator in C is `^`, but  can't figure an easy way to apply the NXOR operator.

Comment: The name gives it away: NOT XOR.  So `NXOR(a,b)` is `~(a ^ b)`.

Comment: On the other hand, C doesn't have a "bit" type, so applying this to, say, 32-bit `unsigned int`s with the values 0 and 1 will result in the values `0xffffffff` or `0xfffffffe`.  Is that really what you want when you say "bitwise"?  If you only want the result in the low bit, and want to leave all the other bits clear, you can do `(~(a ^ b)) & 1`.

Comment: If you're using an integer type to represent a bit, and you *know* `a` and `b` will be exactly 0 or 1 (and not some other truthy value), then `a == b` is basically `a` NXOR `b`.  Or `!a == !b`, which would also allow other non-zero values for true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it from bitwise xor `^` and bitwise not `~`. For example:

```
unsigned nxor(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    return ~(x^y);
}
```

C only has OR, AND, NOT, and XOR. Any other bitwise operator you have to build from those four. Fortunately, you can make any bitwise operator from those four.

If you care about the high bits you can mask them off.

```
unsigned nxor_1bit(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    return 1 & ~(x^y);
}
```